# Display Profile Picture of Users

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I am trying to display the profile pictures of new users registered to a website to show to every user logged onto the website and so far i have been able to display their username but i am having difficulty displaying their profile picture stored in an extended model User profile. How do i make this happen to display it in my templates. A better solution is welcome

```
Profile_tag

def person(context, e):
    """
    Renders a single user object.
    """
    to_return = {
        'user': context ['user'],
        'profile': context['UserProfile.objects.all'],

    }

register = template.Library()
register.inclusion_tag('profile/person.html', takes_context=True)(person)

Person.html


<div class="person">
    <a href="{% url 'profile_detail' user.username %}">
        <span class="username">{{ user.username|slice:"12" }}</span>
        <p> <img src="/static/assets/{{profile_picture}}"  height="100" width="100"></p>

    </a>
</div>


user_list.html

{% load profile_tags %}
{% block main_content %}
    <h1>Newest Users</h1>
    {% friends_for_user user as friend_dict %}
    {% for person in object_list %}
        {% dict_entry_for_item person.username from friend_dict as friend %}

            {% person person %}
            {% ifnotequal person user %}
                <form method="POST" action="{% if friend %}{% url 'sg_unfollow' person.username %}{% else %}{% url 'sg_follow' person.username %}{% endif %}">{%csrf_token%}

                    <input type="submit" value="{% if friend %}Unfollow{% else %}Follow{% endif %}" />
                </form>
            {% endifnotequal %}


        {% endfor %}

Urls.py

urlpatterns = patterns('profile.views',
    url(r'^detail/(?P<username>[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$', 'detail', 
        name='profile_detail'),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

`profile_picture` came from where ?

Extended user model `Profile`  user `Foreignkey` with `User` then

models.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    profile_picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='uploads/avatar')
```

views.py

```
userDetail = Profile.objects.get(user_id=request.session['_auth_user_id'])
templateVar['profile_picture'] = userDetail.profile_picture
```

Comment: so i create a foreign key relationship with my extended user model and request the data from that model right ?

Comment: i want to display all the pictures of other users when lets say a certain user logs in can see the pictures of other users, their username as well